# Git multiple lines commit message validate with regex

Tags: regex, bash, git-bash, githooks, git-commit

I'm working on git commit-msg and I created regex which should validate commit message. When I create regex for one line it works. When I have message in multiple lines it doesn't. I'm working on Windows. This is code I created (regex was checked at regex101.com):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

commit_regex='^(TASK([0-9]+))\ \-\ ([A-Z](.*))[\n\r]{2}(\-\ (.+))(([\n\r]{1}-\ (.+))?)$'
error_msg="Commit message invalid"
if ! grep -iqE "$commit_regex" "$1"; then
    echo "$error_msg" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Sample text to validate:

```
TASK123 - Task description

- commit description
- additional info (optional)
```

Some suggestions how to correct this script? I'm not familiar with git hooks that much and creating bash.

Edit:
When I add z option to like this -izqE it still doesn't work.

Comment: As I know `grep` can't search for a pattern including multiple lines.

Comment: @ElpieKay try with z option.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks!

Comment: it doesn't work with z option unfortunatelly, I don't know if it is git bash, I'm commiting it through tortoise git. File 'commit-msg' is inserted in folder git/hooks